# SSL and TLS synonyms should be reversed

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tags

I tagged my question [tls](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tls) but it appears to be a synonym of [ssl](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ssl). Considering TLS is over 25 years old and has long since replaced SSL, I think that [ssl](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ssl) should be a synonym of [tls](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tls) and not the other way around.

If this were Super User I could see an argument being made that "SSL" is the more familiar phrase, but certainly system administrators should not be confused about what "TLS" is.

Comment: I will wait other opinions, but my opinion is that TLS or SSL should not be a synonyms at all. Iam a Windows admin and TLS config are still a topic

Comment: They are essentially different versions of the same protocol.

Answer (score 0):

TLS is built on-top of the SSL protocol (though they are not interoperable). Likewise, HTTPS security certificates that rely on, e.g. TLS connectivity are still referred to as SSL Certificates (perhaps entirely; I've never heard anyone refer to a "TLS certificate"). People may eventually refer en masse to the technology overall as TLS in the future, but I think reversing the synonyms here now would be premature.

If anything, I think they should be *de*-synonymized; you don't want to confuse the two. Users could theoretically still need to manage SSL connections in intranet environments (or, scarily enough, in internet environments, e.g. healthcare systems that stay perpetually 10-20 years behind the rest of the industry).